# Can C++ Native Multi-Targeting in VS2012 be used to target VS2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, multi-targeting

I have converted my vcproj file into a vcxproj file by loading it in VS2012. Then I added

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

to the PropertyGroup labeled "Globals". I have followed http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx as far as possible to add .props and .target files for the v80 toolset.
When I try to build I get the following error:

```
error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project.
```